# format string to get difference

Tags: php, datetime, string-formatting

How can I get the difference in number of days or weeks or months or years without using mathematics but by using a single function call in between two particular dates?

Or I have to use mathematics?

Suppose

```
$interval->format('%a')
```

Here by using `%a` as the format string outputs the difference in number of days. So what will be for weeks or months or years? In [datetime.format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) its said that

> format
>
> Format accepted by [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

But in date I found no format character as `%a`.

Comment: What a function call like [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: @vascowhite No answer is there for this question. But this answer can answer that question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution in [dateinterval.format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) but for weeks I have to use mathematics may be.

Comment: math is good for brain!

Comment: programming is all maths!

Comment: Yes I know about math. But I do not want to practice the same math again and again. Thats why I want already existing math.